# maven Dependancy conflict No such method with graphql depandancies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, graphql

My application won't start and it seems that there is a dependancy conflict. I can't figure out which dependancy results in the conflict or how to resolve this.

This is the message when I try to start the spring application.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.RootTypeInfo$Companion.fromSchemaDefinitions(RootTypeInfo.kt:16)

The following method did not exist:

    'graphql.language.Type graphql.language.OperationTypeDefinition.getType()'

The calling method's class, com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.RootTypeInfo$Companion, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/home/dante/.m2/repository/com/graphql-java/graphql-java-tools/5.2.4/graphql-java-tools-5.2.4.jar!/com/coxautodev/graphql/tools/RootTypeInfo$Companion.class

The called method's class, graphql.language.OperationTypeDefinition, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/dante/.m2/repository/com/graphql-java/graphql-java/18.1/graphql-java-18.1.jar!/graphql/language/OperationTypeDefinition.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    graphql.language.OperationTypeDefinition: file:/home/dante/.m2/repository/com/graphql-java/graphql-java/18.1/graphql-java-18.1.jar
    graphql.language.AbstractNode: file:/home/dante/.m2/repository/com/graphql-java/graphql-java/18.1/graphql-java-18.1.jar
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>backend</name>
    <description>backend</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <springfox.version>3.0.0</springfox.version>
        <graphql.version>5.0.2</graphql.version>
        <playground.version>5.10.0</playground.version>
        <graphql-java-tools.version>5.2.4</graphql-java-tools.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.9.1</jjwt.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${graphql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${graphql-java-tools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>playground-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${playground.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId> 
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the stacktrace with error from mvn install

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'invocationInputFactory' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'invocationInputFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchema' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'graphql.language.Type graphql.language.OperationTypeDefinition.getType()'
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchema' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'graphql.language.Type graphql.language.OperationTypeDefinition.getType()'
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchema' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'graphql.language.Type graphql.language.OperationTypeDefinition.getType()'
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'graphql.language.Type graphql.language.OperationTypeDefinition.getType()'
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'graphql.language.Type graphql.language.OperationTypeDefinition.getType()'
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'graphql.language.Type graphql.language.OperationTypeDefinition.getType()'
```

I have tried editing the versions but that didn't seem to work.

I have also deleted all the maven cache but also didn't work.

If I delete the dependancy the code compiles. But i'm unsure if this is wanted.

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${graphql-java-tools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any suggestion how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of `graphql-java-tools` (5.2.4) seems very old and not compatible with `graphql-java:18.1` version.

So you need to upgrade your `graphql-java-tools` to the version which is compatible with `graphql-java:18.1` in your classpath.